# Nginx as Reverse Proxy for multiple servers binded to proxy using UNIX sockets - how to reached in LAN

Tags: nginx, web-server, reverse-proxy, unix, socket

I am trying to configure nginx as a reverse proxy for multiple servers on my LAN. They should go out on my WAN with different subdomains.
Unlike the approach described in [Use Nginx as Reverse Proxy for multiple servers](https://serverfault.com/questions/706694/use-nginx-as-reverse-proxy-for-multiple-servers) I want to use UNIX socket for the interprocess communication on my server.

Based on

1. the above [post](https://serverfault.com/questions/706694/use-nginx-as-reverse-proxy-for-multiple-servers)
2. [nginx reverse ssl proxy with multiple subdomains](https://serverfault.com/questions/538803/nginx-reverse-ssl-proxy-with-multiple-subdomains)
3. [Using Nginx as Webserver](https://serverfault.com/questions/677868/using-nginx-as-webserver-and-reverse-proxy)
4. [Nginx to apache reverse proxy, instruct use of unix sockets](https://serverfault.com/questions/433053/nginx-to-apache-reverse-proxy-instruct-use-of-unix-sockets)
5. [Difference between socket- and port-based connection to outer NGINX?](https://meta.discourse.org/t/difference-between-socket-and-port-based-connection-to-outer-nginx/60071)
6. keeping in mind the solution given in [How do I configure Nginx proxy_pass Node.js HTTP server via UNIX socket?](https://serverfault.com/questions/316157/how-do-i-configure-nginx-proxy-pass-node-js-http-server-via-unix-socket)

my configuration shall look something like this below, doesn't it?
In order to keep the main file slim, I would like to outsource the `location` blocks.
I find all on the web more or less but nothing about wow I can reach the servers in within the LAN? Do I need to set up a local DNS server as described in [Running DNS locally for home network](https://superuser.com/questions/45789/running-dns-locally-for-home-network)?

**main proxy file**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    #include letsencrypt.conf;
    server_app1 app1subdomain.domain.eu;
    include app1location.conf
       }

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    #include letsencrypt.conf;
    server_app2 app2subdomain.domain.eu;
    include app1location.conf
       }
```

**app1location.conf** (location file for proxied web server)

```
location / {            
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/app1/app1.com.unix_socket;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; #Authorization
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_buffering off;
    client_max_body_size 0;
    proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
    proxy_redirect off;
           }
```

**app2location.conf** (location file for proxied web server)

```
   location / {            
        proxy_pass http://unix:/home/app2/app2.com.unix_socket;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr; #Authorization
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Connection "";
        proxy_buffering off;
        client_max_body_size 0;
        proxy_read_timeout 36000s;
        proxy_redirect off;
               }
```

Comment: You need to use `include` https://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include to have the `location` config in another file(s)

Comment: thx will get it changed soon, how about the other things?

Comment: `include` it is done, what about the rest?